# spring boot swing application with multiple data sources

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot

I am trying to build a standalone desktop spring application, the application should get the information from multiple data sources. The problem I facing is that `@Autowired Repository` is `null` Bellow is my project setup, I thinking because of the application is desktop I am missing some configuration

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .headless(false)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Main frame() {
        return new Main();
    }
}
```

***DB Config*** Second is configured the same way. Additionally here IntelliJ shows that `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder` bean cannot be autowired

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "notificationEntityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = { "org.thebot.notification.repository" })
public class NotificationDBConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "notificationDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.notificationDatasource")
  public DataSource notificationDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "notificationEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean notificationEntityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
      @Qualifier("notificationDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("org.thebot.notification.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("notification")
        .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "notificationTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager notificationTransactionManager(
      @Qualifier("notificationEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }

}
```

***Repository***

```
@Repository
public interface NotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Notification, Long> {
}
```

***Place where the repository is needed***

```
public class NotificationTab {

  @Autowired
  private PopulationRepository populationRepository;
  private JPanel notificationPanel;
}
```